# How do i deactivate the redirection to about:blank when having experimentalSessionAndOrigin activated?

Tags: javascript, cypress, mocha.js

I have to activate experimentalSessionAndOrigin in cypress.config.js to make the automated process of the registration possible (i use an api for throwaways) and i have to confirm the email. for that i have to press a link on our registration page but for this to work i have to activate experimentalSessionAndOrigin.
problem is that i use it statements for every few steps to make it clear what happens during a headless run. experimentalSessionAndOrigin redirects you after every it statement to an about:blank site to make the test more stable but our site doesnt support that at the current state and it would be a straight up pain in the ass.

i tried using cy.config but it said that experimentalSessionAndOrigin is readonly so this doesnt work. i tried it with experimentalSessionAndOrigin deactivated but this wont work and it says i have to active it.

is there any way to either replace it statements so it gets clear what happens in mochawesome logs/commandline or to deactivate the redirection?

Comment: Please don't add solutions to the question. Create an answer

Comment: Please don't edit your question with `[SOLVED]`. Post answer to your own question and accept that answer

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to remove the answer, and create (and accept) an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to fix it, you can write `testIsolation: "off"` in cypress.config